# Confusing behavior of extension method with new object creation in method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I was trying to understand behavior of Extension methods of c# and found below thing :

Below is extension method on class Program which has one field called SeeIt.

```
public static void Prod(this Program p)
{
   Console.WriteLine("i am in ext- pro" );
   p = new Program();   // look out for this line (call this line as #@2)
   p.SeeIt = 100;
}
```

Now when I call this method like this :

```
var pr = new Program();
pr.SeeIt = 200;

pr.Prod();

COnsole.WriteLine(pr.SeeIt);
```

I see below things :

1. When I comment #@2 line in extension method , result is from extension method i.e. 100.
2. When I keep line #@2 line , result is 200.

I want to know :

- What is exactly happening there with i say p = new Program() in Extension method ?

Comment: Have you tried the debugger flow before posting this question

Comment: There is not much in code to debug..

Comment: Then i assume you don't know about message passing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, it behaves **exactly** the same as it would without the `this`. Extension methods only make the API convenient - they don't change behaviour.

The parameter `p` is not passed `ref`, so as soon as you do `p = new Program();` you have created a separate and unrelated instance that will **not** be available back to the calling code. Consequently, the caller will not see your change, and the `100` will only be visible in `Prod`.

Or more specifically:

```
pr.Prod();
```

is identical to

```
DeclaringType.Prod(pr);
```

which loads the value of `pr` (the reference) onto the stack and calls `Prod` via static-call;

```
public static void Prod(this Program p)
```

at this point, `p` is on the stack in position `arg0`.

```
p = new Program();
```

creates a new object and assigns the value **over** `arg0` - note that value of `pr` (the reference) is not impacted by this, as `arg0` is a separate memory location for the reference.

```
p.SeeIt = 100;
```

assigns a member to the object new object by dereferencing `arg0` - again, the object *at the end of* `pr` knows nothing about this.

Answer (score 0):

It is creating a new instance of `Program` and you are updating the `SeeIt` property of that instance.

a) When #@2 is commented you are updating the value of the original instance of Program and thus the property 100 is set

b) When you create a new instance the old instance is not affected and the property value is not affected

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the reference of p to another instance, which does not affect the reference which you passed to the extension method. I think what you were trying to do was to make parameter p a ref parameter, in which case the references between what was passed to the method and being used in the method itself would be the same.

Unfortunately you cannot do extension methods that take a ref this parameter.

Remember, a reference is basically a pointer to an actual classinstance.